# #include Header Files When They Are In a Different Directory Structure

Tags: c++, directory, header-files

I have done some searching and found similar threads on the proper way to include header files in C++, but none of them quite answered this question.

I know that in order to include a header file in another folder you can simply use the following syntax:

```
#include "../myFolder/myFile.h"
```

But what about when the file is in a different directory structure a bit far removed? 
For example, if something like the following is guaranteed to be true:

Current directory = / f1 / f2 / f3 / f4 / f5 / myFile.cpp

Desired header directory = / f1 / d2 / d3 / d4 / d5 / d6 / myHeader.h

I know that you can set the "Additional Include Directories" property or use a make file, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it from the `#include` statement.

Comment: You can obviously put that whole relative or absolute path in your include statement (which I wouldn't recommend), but I suspect you're looking for something a bit more compact?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am looking to see if there is a way to do it and still have it be relative, so that it doesn't matter what is above f1 (in this example) in the directory structure.

Comment: Well you cans string together ".."'s e.g. `#include ../../../../../../f2/f3/f4/f5/myFile.cpp` which is so ugly I immediately regret typing it.  I'd recommend setting the include path in the makefile.

Comment: Why are people so quick to dismiss the obvious solution? The "Additional Include Directories" is available for a reason - use it.

Answer (score 12):

putting `".."` in `#include` is generally considered ugly and unmaintainable.

Every coherent library you're using (for instance boost) has a single root of header files hierarchy that you should put in your "additional include directories" property. For boost it is something like

```
`C:/lib/boost_1_49`
```

under this directory you usually find a directory called `boost` where all of the headers live. This brings the convention that all boost headers start with:

```
#include <boost/bla/bla.hpp>
```

This also goes for the very project you're writing. You should decide what's the best root for its headers and start all the includes from there.
The only exception to this rule should be headers that are in the same directory. Those can just be included as just a file name `#include "same-dir-header.h"`

You should also make the difference between including with `""` and `<>`. Quotes should be things in your project, angle brackets should be external libraries (or as some would have it - OS and C runtime libraries)

Comment: The trick here is that the directory structure is guaranteed to be the same relatively, but where on the machine the whole thing will live is not. It is sounding more and more like a make file is needed, but I just wanted to know if it was even possible.

Comment: It's also *genuinely* non-portable. We were once trying to write code to work with two compilers: one evaluated relative includes in `.h` files relative to the location of the `.h` file, and the other evaluated the same include relative to the `.c` file. Include paths are the way to go. The basic problem is that the meaning of `..` and `/` in include directives is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5):

To complete the answer from @shoosh, you are supposed to tell your compiler where are those "other" header files. With gcc on windows, if they are in c:\path\to\library, then add the -I option

```
-Ic:\path\to\library
```

Beware of spaces in path, if the location is `c:\my path\to\library`, then:

```
-I"c:\my path\to\library"
```

Other compilers will provide a similar option, on command line or through the IDE.